# Buffon Needle Simulation

Tags: java, math

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class BuffonNeedle
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  double drops = 100;
  int hit = 0;
  for(int r=1; r<=6; r++)
  {
     for(int i = 1; i <= drops; i++)
     {
        double y = Math.random() * 2;

        if(Math.sin(Math.random()*Math.PI) + y >= 2.){
           hit++;
        }   
     }

     System.out.println(drops/hit);
     drops = drops * 10;  
  }
 }
}
```

Why doesn't this yield **Pi** when the constraints are 2 inches apart and the needle is one inch?

The simulation is run 6 times: 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000.

Comment: You did not reset `hit` in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `hit`

```
System.out.println(drops/hit);
drops = drops * 10;  
hit = 0;  //<------reset
```

Comment: If you didn't reset hit, the final result (the result when `r = 6`) will equal to run only inner loop once with `drops = 100 + 1000 + 10000 + 100000 +1000000 + 10000000`. But when I test it with online Java tool, the OP's version 6th result is around `~2.8`, and the only 1 loop version is `~3.14` . Do you think I'm missing something?

Comment: Basically, if you don't reset the value of `hit`, it will ultimately alter `System.out.println(drops/hit);` and as a result you will end up having a smaller value

Comment: Ah, I got it. When `r = 6` , we only get `drops = 10000000`. `hits` are total for `r = 1,..,6` but `drops` are not.